# Creating a file and copying its content to other file in c language

Tags: c, file, copy, file-handling, copying

I need a C program to copy contents of one file to another file along with the following conditions :

1.) The file from which we read data may or may not exist.

2.) The file to which the data is being copied may or may not exist.

If the file exists, then the data shall be directly copied and if the file doesn't exist, there should be an option to create the file ,enter data into it and the later copying the contents of the file into the other file.

I worked out the following code,

At present my modified code is :

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
 FILE *f1,*f2;
 char c;
 char name1[20],name2[20];
 clrscr();
 setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0);
 printf("\nEnter the source file name :");
 scanf("%s",name1);
 if((f1=fopen(name1,"r"))==NULL)
 {
  fclose(f1);
  f1=fopen(name1,"w");
  printf("\nThe specified file does not exist \nNew file will be created");
  printf("\nEnter the data for the new file : ");
  while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
  {
   putc(c,f1);
  }
  fclose(f1); 
 }
 f1=fopen(name1,"r");
 printf("\nEnter the destination file name :");
 scanf("%s",name2);
 f2=fopen(name2,"w+");
 while((c=getc(f1))!=EOF)
 {
  putc(c,f2);
 }
 rewind(f1);
 rewind(f2);
 printf("The data in the source file is :\n");
 while((c=getc(f1))!=EOF)
 {
  printf("%c",c);
 }
 printf("\nThe data in the destination file is :\n");
 while((c=getc(f2))!=EOF)
 {
  printf("%c",c);
 }
 fclose(f1);
 fclose(f2);
 fflush(stdin);
 getch();
}
```

But the program works fine only when the source file already exists . If i create a new file then no input is being taken for the destination file name and the data in the destination file file is blank. So what should i do now?

What should I modify to make it work ?
Suggest me any code of your choice also ... Thank you !

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? "It doesn't work" is non-informative.

Comment: If i create a new file then no input is being taken for the destination file name and the data in the destination file file is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I see several problems in your code but the most important one is that the expression:

```
(c=getc(f1))!=EOF
```

Will always evaluated true, so you'll run infinite loops. If you read `getc` documentation you'll realize that it returns an `int` not a `char`:

[getc documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getc/?kw=getc)

So basically what you're doing is truncating the `EOF`, which is an `int` generally defined as -1, to a `char` when:

```
c=getc(f1)  // At this point C = 255(0xFF) if getc returned EOF
```

And then promoting `c` to an `int` when is compared to `EOF`, since an `int` is big 
enough to hold 255 the comparison made is 255 != -1, which is always true.

To fix that just declare `c` as an `int`.

Some more tips:

You may also want to make sure that it was an end of file condition by using `feof` since `getc` returns `EOF` on other error conditions as well.

You may want to move the `"\n"` to the end of your senteces on `printf` calls to force a flush on stdout. Or alternatively you can add this at the start of your program:

```
setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0);
```

It seems you're storing the file names in `name1` and `name2`, so you may want to remove the double quotes from `fopen` file names so that it actually use them.

When you open `name2` you use write access only but at the end you try to read and display its content, you may want to use `"w+"` as the access mode.

When you're trying to print the resulting data the file handler in `f2` has already been closed. And the file cursors are already at the end of the file so you may want to use `rewind`, e.g.

```
//fclose(f2);
rewind(f1);
rewind(f2);
printf("The data in the source file is :\n");
 while((c=getc(f1))!=EOF)
 {
  printf("%c",c);
 }
 printf("The data in the destination file is :\n");
 while((c=getc(f2))!=EOF)
 {
  printf("%c",c);
 }
 fclose(f1);
 fclose(f2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Julio Moreno

Comment: I added the rewind(f1),rewind(f2) statements ; deleted the fclose(f2) statement ; removed the double quotation marks; changed the mode to w+; and everything went fine...I didn't find any problem with the getc() thing. But the program works fine only when the source file already exists . If i create a new file then no input is being taken for the destination file name and the data in the destination file file is blank. So what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

finally the successful code is :

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
 FILE *f1,*f2;
 char c;
 char name1[20],name2[20];
 clrscr();
 printf("\nEnter the source file name :");
 scanf("%s",name1);
 if((f1=fopen(name1,"r"))==NULL)
 {
  fclose(f1);
  f1=fopen(name1,"w");
  printf("\nThe specified file does not exist \nNew file will be created");
  printf("\nEnter the data for the new file : ");
  while((c=getchar())!='^')
  {
   putc(c,f1);
  }
  fclose(f1); 
 }
 f1=fopen(name1,"r");
 printf("\nEnter the destination file name :");
 scanf("%s",name2);
 f2=fopen(name2,"w+");
 while((c=getc(f1))!=EOF)
 {
  putc(c,f2);
 }
 rewind(f1);
 rewind(f2);
 printf("The data in the source file is :\n");
 while((c=getc(f1))!=EOF)
 {
  printf("%c",c);
 }
 printf("\nThe data in the destination file is :\n");
 while((c=getc(f2))!=EOF)
 {
  printf("%c",c);
 }
 fclose(f1);
 fclose(f2);
 fflush(stdin);
 getch();
}
```